# What is the most compact way to store Oxygen?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, elements

What is the most compact way to store Oxygen? Perhaps I should qualify that as being at room temperature since the most compact form of oxygen is probably liquid oxygen. At room temperature would it be better to store it as rust or compressed air or something else, like hydrogen peroxide?

Comment: Degenerated matter ;)

Comment: Rust? Why not water, then? Or... wait, your body stores a good deal of oxygen, albeit in a chemically bound form. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I think the question is pretty clear. If an organic compound is the most compact way to store water, then what is that compound? Water is a bad answer because hydrogen pyroxide (which I already mentioned) stores oxygen more compactly than water. Did you even read the full question.

Comment: @ShakaBoom Did you even _write_ the full question? If you are really interested in packing as many as possible atoms of O in a given volume, regardless of the energetic factors (this kinda strikes me as odd, but... none of my business, really), then indeed $\ce{H2O2}$ (about 65 moles of O per 1 liter) is a pretty strong contestant and definitely better than water (55 mol/l). However, $\ce{H2SO4}$ (molar mass 98, density 1.84) is even **better** than that.

Comment: Nitrogen Dioxide would be the best as it is liquid and will spontaneously decompose in the presence of the right catalyst

Answer (score 3):

Solid ozone has a density of 1.728 g/cm3 according to [The Density of Solid Ozone](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01513a012?journalCode=jacsat) J. Am. Chem. Soc., 1959, 81, pp 805–806.

Best I can think of at atmospheric pressure, assuming your goal is to store and recover as much pure oxygen as possible in a given volume.

If your goal is just to pack as many oxygen atoms in a given volume, BeO, which has a density of 3.01 g/cm3 is better.

At high pressure there is [metallic oxygen](http://www.esrf.eu/news/spotlight/spotlight89).